# How to configure Redis Session Storage?

Tags: magento2, session, redis

I have successfully managed to configure page caching by Redis on my **Magento 2** store but Session Storage doesn't appear to be working.

I have used this code : http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/redis/redis-session.html

In Magento 1 we had to set `RedisSession.xml` to active. Does something similar need to be done on **Magento 2** ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example of my env.php file. The parts to pay attention to are the `cache` element and the `session` element. You may need to adjust the redis host and port number that it is pointed at. As long as you tell Magento where the redis server lives, it will work.

```
<?php
return [
    'install' => [
        'date' => 'Thu, 02 Nov 2017 13:30:22 +0000'
    ],
    'db' => [
        'connection' => [
            'default' => [
                'username' => 'root',
                'host' => 'mysql',
                'dbname' => 'magento',
                'password' => 'root'
            ],
            'indexer' => [
                'username' => 'root',
                'host' => 'mysql',
                'dbname' => 'magento',
                'password' => 'root'
            ]
        ]
    ],
    'cache' => [
        'frontend' => [
            'default' => [
                'backend' => 'Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis',
                'backend_options' => [
                    'server' => '127.0.0.1',
                    'port' => '6379',
                    'database' => '1'
                ]
            ],
            'page_cache' => [
                'backend' => 'Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis',
                'backend_options' => [
                    'server' => '127.0.0.1',
                    'port' => '6379',
                    'database' => '1'
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ],
    'crypt' => [
        'key' => 'd8567aa9c120960aa842b29c44a0fccd'
    ],
    'session' => [
        'save' => 'redis',
        'redis' => [
            'host' => '127.0.0.1',
            'port' => '6379',
            'database' => '0'
        ]
    ],
    'backend' => [
        'frontName' => 'admin'
    ],
    'resource' => [
        'default_setup' => [
            'connection' => 'default'
        ]
    ],
    'cache_types' => [
        'compiled_config' => 1,
        'config' => 1,
        'layout' => 1,
        'block_html' => 1,
        'collections' => 1,
        'reflection' => 1,
        'db_ddl' => 1,
        'eav' => 1,
        'customer_notification' => 1,
        'full_page' => 1,
        'target_rule' => 1,
        'config_integration' => 1,
        'config_integration_api' => 1,
        'translate' => 1,
        'config_webservice' => 1
    ],
    'MAGE_MODE' => 'developer',
    'system' => [
        'default' => [
            'dev' => [
                'debug' => [
                    'debug_logging' => '0'
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a piece of code further down env.php which defines session as database. This needs to be removed.